# 1and1 mod_rewrite not working with subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to implement a very simple mod_rewrite from one file to another, just to ensure that mod_rewrites are working (obviously I want a more complex rewrite, but first I need rewriting to work).

I have a main domain, example.com, and a subdomain, test.example.com

example.com has a mod_rewrite that works already, ensuring that it uses https.

However, when I try using mod_rewrite on test.example.com, the rewrite doesn't work and I get a 404 error. (This mod_rewrite works on my local XAMPP server)

Here is the .htaccess file in the subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule mod.php result.php
```

I use 1and1 as my web host, was on the phone with them for an hour but they concluded that it was an issue with my script (even though it works on my local machine o.O )

Comment: Let me guess, you have the `.htaccess` with the configuration for your main domain and sub domain on the root folder `public_html` right? Or how is your folder structure for domain and sub domain and where the `.htaccess` are located for each?

Comment: I've to separate folders, 1 each for the domain and Subdomain. each folder Has its own htaccess file

Comment: And your sub domain was configured as an addon to that folder correct? so you have `/home/youraccount/public_html/.htaccess` which is your main domain `.htaccess` and you have `/home/youraccount/public_html/subdomainfoldername/.htaccess` which is your sub domain `.htaccess` and path correct?

Comment: Nope. I'm on my phone so I can't recall the exact structure, but both folders are siblings of each other, and are children of the root folder

Comment: @Prix Brilliant! Adding the `RewriteBase /` line seems to have done the trick. Create an answer with that information and I'll be sure to mark it as correct. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, made it answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^this-is-a-test/$ /result.php [L]
```

Keep in mind it must be on the main folder of your sub domain and to see it in action you need to visit:

```
http://test.domain.dom/this-is-a-test/
```

It must end with a slash and it should show you the content of `result.php` also keep in mind that `result.php` must exist and be on the same folder the `.htaccess` is.